# Layout updates for particular page for particular store

Tags: layout, xml, local.xml, scope

Is there an official way to update a layout via *local.xml* only on grouped product pages **AND** in a particular store?

This would let me update the layout on grouped product pages:

```
<layout>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="addBodyClass">
                <body_class>grouped-product</body_class>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</layout>
```

This would let me update the layout in a particular store:

```
<layout>
    <STORE_storecode>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="addBodyClass">
                <body_class>particular-store</body_class>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </STORE_storecode>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can't you define a new layout in `Design > Themes` ?

Comment: It is a possible workaround, but I wouldn't like to create a new layout only for one small fix.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible. You can of course use one of the mentioned handles, change the template file in there and check the product type or the store in the template file and change the layout accordingly. Although this is not really nice, admitted.

If you can apply your changes via CSS, it should be quite easy. Just use the layout XML you posted and use CSS like that:

```
body.grouped-product.particular-store {
    background: #f00;
}
```

This CSS will only be applied on grouped product pages of a particular store.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. We are doing it this way (yea I know, not nice)

1. Add a new theme, which extends your original theme
2. add a local.xml
3. change the original theme to your extended one.